# Quick question about security hidden service on tor

Tags: web, tor

What's the difference with the v3 and v2 version? Is the security better? How?

What port to choose? I'm currently on 80, is 9000 better? Or is it the same?

If u have any suggestion for the security, that's appreciated :)

Comment: Much more secure, and relays can no longer figure out hidden service addresses like they used to be able to. https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/NextGenOnions and https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec-v3.txt  Port doesn't really matter but if you stick with port 80, no one will need to include a port number when accessing your service.

Comment: Thanks you @drew010 ! then i will stay on port 80. But for v2 the risk remains 0 if we do not leak anything? I think of all the drugs v2 sites for example.

Comment: No, I would still use v3 because "Better crypto (replaced SHA1/DH/RSA1024 with SHA3/ed25519/curve25519)" and "Better onion address security against impersonation." Also cool is described in section 1.7 of the spec, where you can keep your hidden service identity key offline so if the box is compromised, someone can't steal your onion keys and then take over your hidden service address.